# Angular and firestore rules

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm really new to Firebase and Firestore database.

I have an angular project and I use the angular/fire package to communicate with firebase.

I have created a user with user/password method and the call works perfectly.

```
try {
        const user = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.auth, email, password);

        return user;
    } catch (e) {
        return null;
    }
```

After that I would like to store some data in the firestore db and all works fine

```
   addVideoId(storageVideoId: StorageVideoIdModel) {
    const notesRef = collection(this.firestore, 'videoIds');

    return setDoc( doc(notesRef, '' + storageVideoId.date), storageVideoId );
  }
```

After that comes the problem.
I applied a rule in the firestore console:

```
    rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /videoIds/{id} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

well... if I run the addVideoId function.... IT WORKS!
The playgroud tells me that the rule is valid and no operations are permitted, but If I run the addVideoId from angular code without log in, it works anyway....

I really don't understand how to pass that auth object in the rule...

I need some help because are 2 days that I'm stuck on it and I cannot find any example or tutorial that merge authentication with database rules.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: By default, firebase auth will persist your login in local storage, so when the page reloads you automatically log in. So maybe you're logged in even though you think you're not. Do you have anywhere where you're listening to `onAuthStateChanged`? You could use that to double check whether you're logged in our out.

Comment: Yes... That was the trick... I didnt notice that the user stays logged in... I force a log out, disabled the user and reenable it and it works

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to define where the user has permission to write to, otherwise, your users can overwrite each other's data.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{userId}/videoIds/{id} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

this will allow all users to read, but only write to their own collection.